# mod_ajp_proxy configurations and session stickiness

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, mod-proxy, jboss, sticky-sessions

I have a jboss and apache setup hosting my .war file. I have enabled session stickiness to forward requests from apache to jboss . Assume I have 2 apache and 2 jboss instances.

Is the below setting correct? Currently session stickyness is not working and each time request is appended with a new JSESSSION ID.

```
<Proxy balancer://cluster>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    BalancerMember ajp://1.1.1.1:8010/testing keepalive=On loadfactor=1 ping=10 ttl=600
    BalancerMember ajp://2.2.2.2:8010/testing keepalive=On loadfactor=1 ping=10 ttl=600
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /testing balancer://cluster timeout=60 stickysession=JSESSIONID nofailover=On
```

Do I need to add route variable to the balancer member configuration and do i need to enable useJK flag in jboss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the balancer members setting the correct route ID in their session cookies?

Yes, you'll need to define the routes on the `BalancerMember` lines.

Something like this in your `BalancerMember` lines:

```
BalancerMember ajp://1.1.1.1:8010/testing keepalive=On loadfactor=1 ping=10 ttl=600 route=testing1
```

And the associated ID in your Tomcat config must match:

```
<Engine name="whatever-its-named" jvmRoute="testing1">
```